# Constructions: A straight line segment of length pi units.

Tags: geometric-construction

A line segment of length 22/7 units or 3.14 units can be drawn. But how can a line segment be drawn of exactly pi units?

Comment: Start with a line segment of $\tau$ units and half it. - Or if you give me a circle of perimeter one and a line segement of unit length, I could construct length $\pi$ as well. -- Or if you allow me certain other tools beyond straight edge and compasses ...

Comment: You need to clarify what tools you have available.  If you are asking for a construction using straight-edge and compass and a predetermined unit-length, then it is impossible.  Of course, if you are given a ruler of length exactly $\pi$, then it is easy to do.

Comment: Well, if you can roll a circle to make distances you can.  But with classical compass/straightedge constructions you can not.

Comment: Thank. I meant the classical compass and the straight edge constructions.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check it. I have joined today itself. Should I delete the question if anything happens like this?

Comment: "Sorry" About what?, "I didn't check it." Check what. "Should I delete the question if anything happens like this?" What? Something like what?  You asked a perfectly *good* question.  Why should you delete it?

Comment: I meant if the same question has already been asked and missed it by chance.

Comment: "I meant the classical compass and the straight edge constructions. "  I figured you probably did.  But one needs to be clear.  If you have solid cone as a tool you are allowed to make marks on you can do this.  And if you can "curl up" a line you can, of course, uncurl a circle (which dismisses the entire *difficulty* of measuring the length of a curve.)

Comment: Oh... You can delete this question if you want.  But it's marked as a duplicate.  ... But, you didn't do anything wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the transcendence of $\pi$ it is *impossible* to draw a line segment that is *exactly* $\pi$ long. However, one could get close by breaking a circle with radius $\frac 12$ and drawing length of its circumference (perhaps using string around the circle).

Comment: Irrationality is no obstacle per se. The diagonal of a unit square is $\sqrt 2$ units long

Comment: Right.  It is the *transcendence*, not the irrationality alone, that make $\pi$ non-constructable.

Comment: @fleablood that's what I meant. Thanks

Comment: ... which is not to say all *algebraic* numbers are constructable.  Only those of a power of 2 order are.